# Show that $f$ is a constant.

Tags: calculus, functions

For the $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for every $x,y$ real numbers is true, that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le(x-y)^2$

-I think that a good way would be to show, that $f'(x)$ is a constant.

Comment: You need to show that $f'$ is zero, not just any constant.

Comment: @dxiv You're right. I have misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let $x=y+h$ and write the inequality as: $$0 \le \left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| \le |h|$$

Then think the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: and how can I finish the proof with the squeeze theorem? I still can't see it

Comment: @Zauberkerl For a fixed $x$ let $h \to 0$ then the inequalities prove that $f'(x)$ exists and is $0$.